# Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed; SIMPLE COPY AND PASTE

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm just trying to do a simple cut and paste to shift ranges in F:G to an unoccupied cell in `D` but I keep getting that error message. My codes are in the Modules and I don't know what I'm doing wrong! Completely new to VBA. Highlighted portion: `Range("F" & RowNum & ":G" & RowNum).Select`

```
Sub MoveCells(RowNum as Integer)

   Range(“F” & RowNum & ":G" & RowNum).Select

   Selection.Cut

   Range(“D” & RowNum).Select

   ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly, what is the value of `RowNum`?

Comment: Your quotation marks are suspect... re-write the code by hand and I imagine you will find it works. Guessing the code has been copy/pasted from another site

Answer (score 2):

```
Range(“F” & RowNum & ":G" & RowNum).Select
      ^ ^            ^  ^
      | |            |  |
    Chr(147)        Chr(34)
```

The 'quotation marks' around `F` are character 147. To denote a string value you have to use character 34, like the ones around `:G`

This usually happens when copy/pasting code from a website. Delete the quotation marks and re-write them manually to solve the issue.