# Error confusion in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to coding here. I'm trying to execute the code below but excel always pop up with these 2 errors:

> "Run time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object'_global' failed."

and

> "Application - defined or object - defined error."

What's wrong with my code?

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
    Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=Range(“A1”).CurrentRegion)

Worksheets.Add

Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add( _
PivotCache:=PTCache, _
TableDestination:=Range(“A3”))

With PT
.PivotFields(“Region”).Orientation = xlPageField
.PivotFields(“Month”).Orientation = xlColumnField
.PivotFields(“SalesRep”).Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields(“Sales”).Orientation = xlDataField
.DisplayFieldCaptions = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I answered this yesterday: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35742622/4240221)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it the “ that is causing issues. Replacing with " made the code run just fine on my machine:

```
'replaced “ ” with "
Sub CreatePivotTable()
    Dim PTCache As PivotCache
    Dim PT As PivotTable
        Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

    Worksheets.Add

    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add( _
    PivotCache:=PTCache, _
    TableDestination:=Range("A3"))

    With PT
        .PivotFields("Region").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("Month").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("SalesRep").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Sales").Orientation = xlDataField
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = False
    End With
End Sub
```